# What methods are used in order to prove the independence of two variables in statistics?

Tags: r, independence

I have four variables (attributes) describing student. They are categorical data. I need to prove that these variables are independent.

The easiest way (even not sufficient) is to see the correlation between pairs of these variables.

Could you please kindly help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You *can't* prove independence (at least not without the whole population). You can sometimes identify dependence (e.g. by a chi-square test), but failure to identify dependence is not at all the same as proving independence. If small amounts of dependence can be tolerated, you might consider some form of equivalence test (provided you're only concerned with the particular kinds of dependence in your equivalence test).

Comment: It seems unlikely that any student attributes would truly be independent. Could you elaborate on why you want to demonstrate independence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of categorical variables, you can either perform a [$G$-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test) or a [$X^2$-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) of independence.
If you do not have a lot of samples, you may consider performing [Fisher's exact test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) instead.

Comment: That's not really correct. Failure to reject the null does *not* imply accepting it!

Comment: You are of course correct. I did not intend to imply this in my answer. As Glen_b already mentioned, you can't prove independence. In practice however, such tests are often used to "decide" whether dependence or independence holds.